# Matplotlib - Resizing x-axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.array([0,0.1,0.3,0.5])
Y = 3*(X**2)
plt.xticks(X,X)
plt.plot(X,Y)
```

[image]

Is there a way to resize the x-axis for equally spaced intervals and adjust the graph with this values? For example, I want to resize the intervals `[0,0.1]` `[0.1,0.3]` `[0.3,0.5]` for size 0.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could plot just the y values (so the x axis will be given by `range(len(Y))`) and use the values of `X` as ticklabels,

```
X = np.array([0,0.1,0.3,0.5])
Y = 3*(X**2)
plt.xticks(range(len(X)),X)
plt.plot(Y)
```

or more generally,

```
X = range(Y.size)
Xlabels = [0,0.1,0.3,0.5]
plt.xticks(X, Xlabels)
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's what i need!